# Unexpected token, expected , for seletedValues.filter method

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am facing a syntax error at this line:

```
queryComponents: prevState.seletedValues.filter((a, i) => (i !== index));
```

I am trying to replace `splice` with `filter`. I tried to fix it by adding brackets and removing brackets, but that didn't help. How can I fix it?

Here's the code fragment:

```
removeSelectedValue = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        queryComponents: prevState.seletedValues.filter((a, i) => (i !== index));
    });
};
```

[The full code is on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/1r54yyj797).

Comment: Remove `;`  in the filter function end and close setState function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please ensure that **all** necessary code is here **on-site**, not just linked. 
Your best bet for that is to include **runnable** [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Also, use actual sentences, not bullet points of sentence fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget an addition closing `)` on line 40 to close this.setState.

```
 removeSelectedValue = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
              queryComponents: prevState.seletedValues.filter((a, i) => (i !== index))
    }));
};
```

Comment: hey I updated the code but still I am faicng error when I click remove button...providing my updated snadbox code here https://codesandbox.io/s/1r54yyj797

Comment: I did notice that . "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

Comment: Typo : selectedValue.push(obj);  <----
Should be selectedValues

Comment: @NickLee it means your `prevState.seletedValues` itself is undefined.

Comment: Because seletedValues is not set

Comment: When a problem is caused by a typo, don't post an answer. Post a comment (unless it's already been posted) and (when you have enough rep) vote to close as a typo (it's one of the "off-topic" close reasons).